# Can i add sticky header view to a Linear Layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a linear layout which show full list on the screen without lists' scrolling.I used listview but wasnot able to show all items at same time without scroll.Now i want to add sticky header view to this list in linear layout.What approach should i choose?

```
 l1= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        l2= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list2);

        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://taskism.com").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        Login_api newcall=retrofit.create(Login_api.class);
        Call<inst_model> mycall=newcall.gettasksteplist("tasksteplist","223","62");
        mycall.enqueue(new Callback<inst_model>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<inst_model> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                tasksteps=response.body().getTasksteps();
                adapter1=new adapter1(instructions.this,R.layout.adapter1,tasksteps);

                for (int i = 0; i < adapter1.getCount(); i++) {
                    View view = adapter1.getView(i, null, l1);
                    l1.addView(view);
                }




            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }



        });
        Login_api allcomnt=retrofit.create(Login_api.class);
        Call<Commentall> allcomm=allcomnt.commentall("commentall", "222", "14");
        allcomm.enqueue(new Callback<Commentall>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Commentall> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                List<Comment> allcom=response.body().getComments();
                adapter2 =new adapter2(instructions.this,R.layout.adapter2,allcom);

                for (int i = 0; i < adapter2.getCount(); i++) {
                    View view = adapter2.getView(i, null, l2);
                    l2.addView(view);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
```

and the layout is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/instname"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Gairy J"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/steps"
        android:text="Steps"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_cancel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/instname"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/steps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Comments"
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_below="@id/list1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/comment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can have structure like this. which will solve ur problem.
`<Scrollview>
<---Header Layout-->
<ListView/>
</scrollview>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to add sticky header and other

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: thanks but my problem was solved                                         https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems